# C# Update CSV cell

Tags: c#, button, combobox

I'm just starting to code so all help is appreciated I have searched everywhere and couldn't find a way to do this, I need to update a specific cell in an CSV file using a button (for the update) and a combobox (that has the value in this case some names) thanks in advance :)

Comment: Can you post any code that you have attempted?

Answer (score 1):

No need for `interops`, or other s$!^&... It's `.csv`, which is essentially text file where data is separated by semicolons and new lines (if not specially formatted)...

First, as @WynDiesel said, try to change data in `.csv` to some hard-coded value. Let's say you need to change data in cell `[X, Y]` (X-th column, Y-th row). The easiest (though not most efficient way) of doing this would be reading all lines of the `.csv` file with `StreamReader` or using other method and saving those lines to, let's say, string array which we will call `rowsArray`. Then access `Y-th` row, split it using semicolon delimiter and save the result to other string array (let's call this one `dataArray`).

```
string[] dataArray = string.Split(';', rowsArray[Y]);
```

Then change `X-th` value of that `dataArray`.

```
dataArray[X] = myNewValue;
```

After this, do

```
rowsArray[Y] = string.Join(";", dataArray)`.
```

Now you only need to write all the data back to the original file.

As for UI thing, just use `OnClick` event for the button, get the value of `ComboBox` and use the function we earlier created for writing that value to the `.csv` file.

Comment: Agreed, interops and (my personal experience) working with Excel directly usually ends in tears.

Answer (score 0):

Forget about the combobox/UI first.

You'll need to write a piece of code that can take a filename, read all the lines from that file, and then for a certain line in that file, break it down into fields (by a delimeter), then rebuild that line up with the new value you want in, build the file up again, and write it again. Once you have done this, you start building your UI around this.

Start breaking your problem down into smaller problems, and solve the smallest problem first.

Answer (score 0):

You only need **Micorosft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll**

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var fileName = @"myexcel.xlsx";


    if (File.Exists(fileName))
    {
        try
        {
            var excelApp = new Excel.Application();
            var xlWorkBook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(fileName);

            var xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelApp.ActiveSheet;
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, "A"] = "Some thing";
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, "B"] = "Other thing";
            xlWorkSheet.SaveAs(fileName);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //some error handling;
        }
    }
}
```

You can read more about opening/writing/reading excel files here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interop/how-to-access-office-onterop-objects